# Ocultar categorias vacias en wordpress

Tags: php, html5, wordpress, foreach

Buen día comunidad, realize un filtro de wordpress llamando a todas las categorias de entradas e imprimiendolas en una lista , así tengo el codigo

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'hide_empty'    => 0,
    'exclude'    => '1',
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
));
```

y los imprimo con un foreach

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {printf( '<li class=""><a
href="https://mipagina.com/?category_name=%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
   esc_html($category->slug),
   esc_html($category->name)
 );
}
```

Esto me trae las categorias independientemente si tienen articulos o no, ahora necesito ocultar las categorias vacias, he tratado con hide_empy pero no lo he logrado, he intentado de todo y ya me siento bloqueado.

Comment: Al pasar `'hide_empty'    => 0,` le estás diciendo que no oculte las vacías (`0` es igual a `false`, igual a *no ocultes las vacías*). Prueba a pasarle `'hide_empty'    => TRUE,`. Incluso hay quienes dicen que WP por defecto no muestra las categorías vacías, puedes probar sin nada a ver que pasa. Y, asegúrate de que realmente están vacías.

Answer (score 0):

En el código estás diciendo precisamente *que muestre las vacías* al pasar este argumento:

```
'hide_empty'    => 0,
```

`0` equivale a `FALSE`.

Wordpress oculta las categorías vacías por defecto, por lo que puedes quitar ese argumento:

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'exclude'    => '1',
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
));
```

Si de todos modos lo quieres poner de forma explícita, tendría que ser así:

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'hide_empty'    => TRUE,
    'exclude'    => '1',
    'taxonomy' => 'category'
));
```

En vez de `TRUE` puedes poner un `1`. Yo prefiero usar los valores por su tipo.

Lo he probado y me funciona. Si no te funciona, revisa  si hay algún plugin que está interfiriendo.